# Compare more than one values with each other

Tags: php

I have about 20 different variables and i want to compare this variables with each other to check weather they are equal or not.

**Example**

```
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;
$var3 = 1;
$var4 = 8;
.
.
.
$var10 = 2;
```

Now i want to check...

```
if($var1 == $var2 || $var1 == $var3 || $var1 == $var4 || ......... || $var2 == $var3 || $var2 == $var4 || ............. || $var8 = $var9 || $var8 == $var10 ||...)
{
    echo 'At-least two variables have same value';
}
```

I am finding for an easy to do this. Any Suggestions?

Comment: So you want to check if *all* variables have the same value?

Comment: Put your variables in an array then create another array from this one using array_unique, if the count of the 2 array is different you have at least 2 identical values.

Comment: @decereé no i want to check any two variables have same value?

Comment: @yent, just put that in an answer! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$arr = array($var1, $var2, ... , $var10);

if (count($arr) !== count(array_unique($arr))) {
  echo 'At-least two variables have same value';
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to find out if any of the variables are duplicates, put them in an array and use the [`array_count_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

> `array_count_values()` returns an *array* using the values of the *input* array as keys and their frequency in input as values.

If you have any values greater than 1 in the result, there is a match.

E.g.

```
$values = array(1,2,3,1);
if(max(array_count_values($values)) > 1) {
   ...
```

Comment: I think this is actually more efficient that the `count` + `array_unique` approach, plus it offers a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

firstly,save them to an array,and everything becomes easy

```
$list=array("1"=>$var1,"2"=>$var2,......,"10"=>$var10);
$list2=array_unique($list);
if(count($list2) != count($list))
    echo 'At-least two variables have same value';
```